# checking spanning set to the equal or not

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

Let $w,x,y,z$ be elements of some real vector space.
Suppose $z=-3x-4y$ and $w=-3x+4y-z$.

Which of the following statement is true?

A. span$(x,y)$=span$(x,w,z)$

B. span$(y)$=span$(w)$

C. span$(x,z)$=span$(y,w)$

D. span$(x,y)$=span$(w)$

Now I proceed to find the RREF as follows:

$$z=-3x-4y$$

$$\implies 3x+4y+z=0$$

$$w=-3x+4y-z$$

$$\implies 3x-4y+z+w=0$$

Then we have

$$\begin{pmatrix}3&4&1&0\\3&-4&1&1\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

So basically I can see if the two sets are subsets of each other so that the sets would be equal. But I think there should be a simpler way. Could anyone help?

Comment: The matrix equation you wrote does not make sense. $x, y, z, w$ here are vectors, not real numbers.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that. Thanks.

Comment: But to answer your question, see if you can write each of the Spans in a set-building notation, trying to express linear combinations in terms of $x$ and $y$ only. Then you should get a better insight.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it.

Since I have $y=\frac{1}{8}w$ and $\frac{1}{6}w=-x-\frac{1}{3}z$, I can see "controlling y implies I can control w too". Then basically it is a game of degree of freedom.

Hence only A and B are true.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see for A how to proceed:

Let us first recall that if $X$ and $Y$ denote two sets, $X=Y \iff (X\subset Y$ and $Y \subset X$)

- $x\in $ span$(x,w,z); 4y=-3x-z ;$ so $y=-\frac34x-\frac14z\in $ span$(x,w,z);$ finally, span$(x,y)\subset $ span$(x,w,z);$
- $z=-3x-4y\in$ span$(x,y)$; so also $w=-3x+4y-z$; $x\in $ span$(x,y)$; finally span$(x,w,z)\subset$span$(x,y);$
- finally, $\color{green}($span$(x,y)=$ span$(x,w,z)\color{green})$ is TRUE.